# Struts2 : get Value from the session object

Tags: struts2

I have a problem related to a Struts2 session.
My database code is:

```
public LinkedList<AddNewPatientBean> listOfCheckinPat(AddNewPatientBean patientBean) {

    LinkedList<AddNewPatientBean> listOfCheckin = new LinkedList<AddNewPatientBean>();
    int checkinVal = 1;
    int checkinVal1 = 1;
    String selectQuery = " select * from pat_checkin where dispName=? AND ownerId=? AND checkIn=? ";
    //   lockValue.add(new AddNewPatientBean("1"));
       System.out.println("dispname1  "+patientBean.getDispName());
       System.out.println("dispname2  "+patientBean.getOwnerId());
       System.out.println("dispname3  "+checkinVal);

    try {
        con = DBConnection.dbConn();
        pStatement = con.prepareStatement(selectQuery);
        pStatement.setString(1, patientBean.getDispName());
        pStatement.setString(2, patientBean.getOwnerId());
        pStatement.setInt(3, checkinVal);
        rs = pStatement.executeQuery();
        while (rs.next()) {
            checkinVal1++;
            listOfCheckin.add(new AddNewPatientBean(rs.getInt("checkIn_id"),rs.getInt("pat_id"),rs.getString("patName"),rs.getString("dispName"),rs.getString("ownerId"),rs.getInt("checkIn")));
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            System.out.println("checked detail dao size "+listOfCheckin.size()+"     RS VAL "+rs+"  "+checkinVal1);
            con.close();
            pStatement.close();
            rs.close();

        } catch (Exception e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    return listOfCheckin;
}
```

Bean Class code constructor:

```
public AddNewPatientBean(int checkin_id, int id, String patName, String dispName, String usermail, int chkinOrchkoutVal) {
    super();
    this.checkin_id = checkin_id;
    this.id = id;
    this.patName = patName;
    this.dispName = dispName;
    this.useremail = usermail;
    this.chkinOrchkoutVal = chkinOrchkoutVal;
}
```

This the Action Class:

```
//list
System.out.println("Owner ID is ------->>>  "+ownerId);
AddNewPatientBean bean = new AddNewPatientBean(r3, ownerId,subOwnerId);
listCheckinPat = addNewPatServInter.listOfCheckinPatServ(bean);
for( AddNewPatientBean nsns : listCheckinPat) {
      System.out.println("heoollmmmmm*****************   "+nsns.getPatName());
      System.out.println("heoollmmmmm*****************   "+nsns.getId());
      System.out.println("heoollmmmmm*****************   "+nsns.getChkinOrchkoutVal());

      session.put("waitList", listCheckinPat);
}
```

Till here everything is running fine. Now I want to get the value from the session in a JSP page.
How can I get the value?

Comment: And what have you tried?

Comment: Depends what you want to do with the value, do you want to show a list? Also to show something on a JSP you don't have to put it in the session, the action is exposed during the request to the view (JSP) so simply provide getters for the properties. For means of accessing such properties see:  http://struts.apache.org/2.3.7/docs/tag-reference.html

Answer (score 1):

You can access it as `<s:property value='#session.waitList'/>` (OGNL Expressions)

Answer (score 1):

You can write as such:

```
<s:iterator value='%{session.test}' >
```

other properties:

```
<s:property value="#application.anAppAttribute" /> 
<s:property value="#session.aSessionAttribute" /> 
<s:property value="#request.aRequestAttribute" /> 
<s:property value="#parameters.aRequestParameter" />
```